# Google Earth Engine: Accessing image properties inside .map() function

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

### Background

I would like to access properties of images within an ImageCollection, using the `.map()` function. Here is an example for an image collection, using yearly rainfall for Tanzania ([link to code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/da64fbcde00f01c8af5f3691e8fbb72b)):

```
// Define ROI
var TZ_outline = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017')
    .filterMetadata('country_na', 'equals', 'Tanzania');

// Define time range
var startyear = 2015;
var endyear = 2019; 

// List years
var years = ee.List.sequence(startyear,endyear);

//Aggregate total rainfall over year
var yearTotal = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
    years.map(function(y) {
        var start = ee.String(ee.Number(y).subtract(1).int()).cat('-05-01') // start rain year from May April-1
        var end = ee.String(ee.Number(y).int()).cat('-04-30')
        
        return ee.ImageCollection('UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/PENTAD')
                  .map(function(im){return(im.clip(TZ_outline))})
                  .filterDate(start, end)
                  .sum()
                  .set('year', y);
    })
    .flatten()
);
```

For a single image, I would use `.get()` to access a property, and this works for my example:

```
print(yearTotal.first().get('year'))
```

Using this code within the `.map()` function returns an error:

```
var col = yearTotal.map(function(img) {
 var year = img.get('year')
 print(year)
 return(year)
});
```

[image]

### Question

How do I make this work? Does it have something to do with server vs. client side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.map()` is a server-side function and `print` is a client-side function. They both cannot be mixed ([read more on this here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/debugging#mapped-functions)).

Earth engine has a helpful function called `.aggregate_array()` for the task you mentioned. Add this line `print(yearTotal.aggregate_array('year'))` to the end of your script and it will output `year` property of all images in your `yearTotal` collection.

[Link to complete code.](https://code.earthengine.google.com/5201c0173085a6aea171d768af051079)